# SQL search user and user state from city_id

Tags: php, mysql, join

I don't know if the title makes any sense, but here is the situation: See 4 tables below

**User Table**(There is 200 + user)

```
+-------+---------+-------------------+---------+
|iduser |  user   |      address      |  idcity |
+-------+---------+-------------------+---------+
|   1   | person1 | some address      |     123 |
|   2   | person2 | another address   |     542 |
|   3   | person3 | different address |     623 |
+-------+---------+-------------------+---------+
```

**City Table**

```
+---------+-------+----------+
| idcity  | city  | idstate  |
+---------+-------+----------+
|    123  | city1 |     1    |
|    542  | city2 |     2    |
|    623  | city3 |     3    |
+---------+-------+----------+
```

**State Table**

```
+---------+--------+------------+
| idstate | state  | idcountry  |
+---------+--------+------------+
|     1   | state1 |      4     |
|     2   | state2 |      5     |
|     3   | state3 |      6     |
+---------+--------+------------+
```

**Country Table**

```
    +-----------+----------+
    | idcountry |  country |
    +-----------+----------+
    |     4     | country1 |
    |     5     | country2 |
    |     6     | country3 |
    +-----------+----------+
```

**NOTE** = I need to find out all people that belong to `State` and search by `idcity`

**Output**

```
+--------+----------+-------------------+---------+---------+
| iduser |   user   |      address      |  idcity |  state  |
+--------+----------+-------------------+---------+---------+
|   11   | person11 | some address      |     123 |  state1 |
|    2   | person2  | another address   |     123 |  state1 |
|   13   | person13 | different address |     123 |  state1 |
+--------+----------+-------------------+---------+---------+
```

or

```
+--------+----------+-------------------+---------+---------+
| iduser |   user   |      address      |  idcity |  state  |
+--------+----------+-------------------+---------+---------+
|   20   | person20 | some address      |     542 |  state3 |
|   12   | person12 | another address   |     542 |  state3 |
|   33   | person33 | different address |     542 |  state3 |
+--------+----------+-------------------+---------+---------+
```

How  to achieve this with a single JOIN?I tried combining the two table within a JOIN(in query) which doesn't feel right somehow. Please Help how can i fix this pblm. Thankyou

Comment: you have to join city and state table with user table, with a single JOIN this is not possible

Comment: yes, but like search by idcity for example :-select u.iduser,u.user,u.address,u.idcity,s.state 
From usertable u inner join ................ where idcity="542"

Answer (score 1):

Try like this,

```
select u.iduser,u.user,u.address,u.idcity,s.state 
From usertable u
inner join city c on c.idcity=u.idcity
inner join state s on s.idstate=c.idstate
```

Comment: OP ask result in single join

Answer (score 1):

To get the city id

```
select 
 c.idcity 
from city c 
where c.idcity = <someidcity>
```

To join state name

```
select 
  c.idcity, 
  s.state
from city c
join state s on s.idstate = c.idstate
where c.idcity = <someidcity>
```

Then to join user

```
select 
  u.iduser,
  u.user,
  u.address,
  c.idcity, 
  s.state
from city c
join state s on s.idstate = c.idstate
join user u on u.idcity = c.idcity
where c.idcity = <someidcity>
```

You can't do that in a single join, as you wanna infos (other than ids) from table user and table state, which have no direct relationship.

Comment: OP ask result in single join

Comment: @SandipPatel Yup, but he also shows the desired output...

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT
    a.iduser,
    a.user,
    a.address,
    b.idcity,
    c.state
FROM
    users a
INNER JOIN
    cities b
ON
    a.idcity=b.idcity
INNER JOIN
    states c
ON
    b.idstate=c.idstate
WHERE
    c.state='myState'
AND b.city='myCity'
```